# How to integrate playwright and perfecto to run the test in perfecto cloud

Tags: ui-automation, playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript, perfecto

I have an automated test created in Playwright using Typescript. I would like run the same in perfecto cloud (for both web and mobile) but I could not find any documentation for Perfecto-Playwright integration. Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Are you under any company proxy/VPN? Did you try setting up WDIO proxy?
https://webdriver.io/docs/proxy/